# Create multiple documents in Cloud Firestore at the same time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to create multiple documents against a collection using Cloud Firestore in the same transaction?

I'm looking at the documentation on [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). Unless I'm mistaken (I'm new to Firebase, so could be the case) these examples are meant to demonstrate 'batched writes' but the examples only show a single field being updated.

Comment: The number of fields being added to a new document shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I didn't think it would. I'm asking can you create multiple new documents in a collection in one transaction.

Comment: Ok, I was confused by your last sentence that referred to fields.

Comment: @DougStevenson I also want to do the same thing he said, in terms of creating multiple documents in a collection in one transaction. I have checked the documentation but there's nothing indicating such but I know it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Batched writes can work for both updating a single field on multiple documents, or creating a bunch of documents at once.

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Comment: can you please explain with any example?

Comment: Yes please. I also want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to see a similar case i had which i solved. It talked about a collection with its documents being automatically created when a document is created. You will get an idea on how to solve your issue from it.

The link is thus: [When collection is created, the documents are added to it at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923169/when-collection-is-created-the-documents-are-added-to-it-at-once/60925489#60925489)

I hope it helps.