# When collection is created, the documents are added to it at once

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Still learning firestore, i want to write a function which would create multiple documents upon the creation of a collection at once. So i wrote this code to try it out. i saw the code as an answer to something similar.

```
    const fsRef = admin.firestore();

export const moreCreations = functions.firestore
      .document(
        "dev_env/schools/school_collections/KithAndKin7394/students/{userID}"
      )
      .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const newSchoolRef = fsRef
          .collection("dev_env")
          .doc("schools")
          .collection("school_collections")
          .doc("KithAndKin7394")
          .collection("students")
          .doc(snap.id);

         // Trying something on documents

         const documentIds = [
           'CRK_IRK',
           'PHE',
           'agricScience',
           'basicScience',
           'basicTechnology',
           'businessStudies',
           'computerStudies',
           'creativeArts',
           'english',
           'frenchLanguage',
           'hausaLanguage',
           'homeEconomics',
           'iboLanguage',
           'maths',
           'socialStudies',
           'yoruba'
         ];

         const batch = fsRef.batch();
         const data ={};
         const setbatch = documentIds.forEach(docId => {
          batch.set(newSchoolRef.collection('JSS1').doc('${docId}'), data);
         })
         batch. commit().then(response => {
           console.log('Success');
         }).catch(err => {
           console.error(err);
         })
      });
```

I am getting these errors:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\brighterbrains\functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json


ERROR: C:/brighterbrains/functions/src/index.ts:168:23 - Expression has type `void`. Put it on its own line as a statement.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-30T02_04_34_455Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

What i want is when the collection "JSS1" is created, the documents "documentsId" are added to it at once. The code is from this forum but it is not working. Please can anyone point my mistake and help with me with the corrections? The documentation doesn't do or say anything about such actions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code isn't even being run yet.  The TypeScript compiler is saying there's an error on line 168.  Look into that first.

Comment: Hi Doug, like i said earlier i am new to this and i got the code from this from and here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012176/firstore-create-multiple-documents-at-once

From his code, he didn't make any use of that const on line 168

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual code, and mark which line is 168 to make it easier to see what you're seeing.  We shouldn't have to follow links.

Comment: The code i uploaded is the actual code just a slight change in the documentsId array. i added more values to it but the code is the entire code.

Comment: And line 168 is which one?  It doesn't even look like there are more than 50 lines of code present in the question.  Please edit the question to be perfectly clear which line the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Try removing `const setbatch = ` before the `forEach` - it doesn't have a return value

Answer (score 1):

Remove `const setbatch =` from before the `forEach()`. It doesn't have a return value.

Comment: i did and the function deployed perfectly BUT the desired result wasn't achieved. I follwed an example from a post on this forum and the link is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012176/firstore-create-multiple-documents-at-once

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Below is the updated code:

```
export const moreCreations = functions.firestore
  .document(
    "dev_env/schools/school_collections/KithAndKin7394/students/{userID}"
  )
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newSchoolRef = fsRef
      .collection("dev_env")
      .doc("schools")
      .collection("school_collections")
      .doc("KithAndKin7394")
      .collection("students")
      .doc(snap.id);

     // Trying something on documents

     const documentIds = [
       'CRK_IRK',
       'PHE',
       'agricScience',
       'basicScience',
       'basicTechnology',
       'businessStudies',
       'computerStudies',
       'creativeArts',
       'english',
       'frenchLanguage',
       'hausaLanguage',
       'homeEconomics',
       'iboLanguage',
       'maths',
       'socialStudies',
       'yoruba'
     ];

     const batch = fsRef.batch();
     const data ={};
      documentIds.forEach(docId => {
      batch.set(newSchoolRef.collection('JSS1').doc(docId), data);
     })
     batch.commit().then(response => {
       console.log('Success');
     }).catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
     })
  });
```

It deployed successfully and upon creation of a document, the collection JSS1 is automatically created with the documents under the documentsId array automatically added.

I wanna thank @samthecodingman for helping me spot the area i need to edit. And @DougStevenson too.

Comment: You could also flatten `const newSchoolRef = ...` to just `const newSchoolRef = snap.ref`.